# TypeError when selecting rows by DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, intersection

I would like to select rows in a dataframe by retaining those sharing the same timestamps as that of another dataframe

In short, I want to select lines that should be the same based on timestamp values. In a 2nd step I intend to check that values in columns are indeed the same.

As an example, here are some lines of code to reproduce the type of input dataframes I am working with.

```
import pandas as pd

ts_list_5m_1 = [
          'Sun Dec 22 2019 07:40:00 GMT-0100',
          'Sun Dec 22 2019 07:45:00 GMT-0100',
          'Sun Dec 22 2019 07:50:00 GMT-0100',
          'Sun Dec 22 2019 07:55:00 GMT-0100']

ts_list_5m_2 = [
          'Sun Dec 22 2019 07:50:00 GMT-0100',
          'Sun Dec 22 2019 07:55:00 GMT-0100',
          'Sun Dec 22 2019 08:00:00 GMT-0100',
          'Sun Dec 22 2019 08:05:00 GMT-0100']

op_list_5m_1 = [7134.0, 7134.34, 7135.03, 7131.74]
op_list_5m_2 = [7135.03, 7131.74, 7234.50, 7334.88]

GC_5m_1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ts_list_5m_1, op_list_5m_1)), columns =['Timestamp', 'Open'])
GC_5m_2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ts_list_5m_2, op_list_5m_2)), columns =['Timestamp', 'Open'])

GC_5m_1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(GC_5m_1['Timestamp'], utc=True)
GC_5m_2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(GC_5m_2['Timestamp'], utc=True)

GC_5m_1.set_index('Timestamp', inplace = True, verify_integrity = True)
GC_5m_2.set_index('Timestamp', inplace = True, verify_integrity = True)
```

To get the list of shared timestamps, I use following line of code:

```
shared_TS = GC_5m_1.index.intersection(GC_5m_2.index)
```

And then, I would like to get data from both dataframes for these index. I am using this line.

```
GC_5m_1.loc[shared_TS]
```

But this throws me following error.

```
raise TypeError("unhashable type: %r" % type(self).__name__)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'DatetimeIndex'
```

Please, do you have any idea how I can get this sub-dataframe properly?
I intend then to use it with the merge function (+indicator) to check that values in 'Open' column are indeed the same.

I thank you in advance for your help.
Have a good day,
Bests,

Comment: For me working correct, what is your pandas version?

Comment: oh my... I am lost, yes it works. I don't know what was wrong initially... feel so dumb... :)

Comment: Its happens, no problem.